# Create several pie charts in R from lists

Tags: r, plot, pie-chart

I want to create several pie charts at once, I have a list of the names:

```
 [1]   361   456   745   858  1294  1297  2360  2872  3034  5118  5189...
```

So the first pie chart should be labeled '361', and so on.

Then I have several lists with values for each pie chart

```
[1] 102  99 107  30   2   8  24  16  57 117 ...
[1] 1 1 2 1 0 0 0 1 1 2 ...
[1] 4 2 2 1 3 0 0 1 1 2 ...
```

So for '361', the first element is 102, the second is 1 and the third is 4. The total is 107.

I want to do all of the charts at once.

Comment: All at once?   Do you want to pop up 10 separate graphics windows?  Have 10 small pie charts on a single window?

Comment: No, I want to create one big plot with all the graphics

Comment: Your list of "names" (361, 451 ..) has 10 elements. Your first row of data has 16 elements and the other two rows have 21 elements. How many graphs are there supposed to be?

Comment: fixed, they all have the same size

Answer (score 2):

One way to get that is by setting `par("mfrow")`.  I also adjusted the margins a bit to eliminate some unwanted whitespace around the charts.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,5), mar=rep(0, 4), oma=rep(0,4))
for(i in 1:length(names)) {
    pie(df[i, ][df[i,] > 0], labels=(1:3)[df[i,] > 0])
    title(names[i], line = -3) }
```

[image: Multiple pie charts]

**Data**

```
## data
names = c(361, 456, 745, 858, 1294, 1297, 2360, 2872, 3034, 5118, 5189)
x = c(102,  99, 107,  30,   2,   8,  24,  16,  57, 117)
y = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2)
z = c(4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2)
df = data.frame(x,y,z)
```