# How can I save a number of piecharts in a list?

Tags: r, loops, save, pie-chart

I am trying to make a function. The function has to provide me a list of piecharts after i give it a data frame with grades.

I am failing to see what's going wrong, if you could give me a little push so I can get on with my report :)

```
function_pie.chart<- function(data) {
   pie_charts <- list()
   for(i in 1:ncol(data)) {

       slices <- c(count_if(lt(5.5), data[,i]), count_if(gt(5.4),data[,i]))
       lbls <- c("Passed", "Failed")
       pct <- round(slices/sum(slices)*100)
       lbls <- paste(lbls, pct)
       lbls <- paste(lbls,"%",sep="")
       p1 <- eval(substitute(pie(slices,labels = lbls, 
                           col=rainbow(length(lbls)),
                           main=colnames(data[,i]))))
       pie_charts[[i]] <- p1
     }
}
```

I expect the output to be a list so I can easily plot an image with multiple piecharts. The output on the other hand gives me this error:

> "Error in seq.int(x[i], x[i + 1], length.out = n) :    'length.out'
>   must be a non-negative number"

Sample data:

```
data <- data.frame(
`BSTAT-THI Beschrijvende Statistiek` = c(7.3, 6.3, 5.8, 6.9, 5.7, 8.9, 6.1, 7, 8.1, 7.1, 6.2, 6.5, 7, 4.9, 9, 6.2, 5.6, 7.3, 6.6, 7.7, 8.3, 7.3, 7.1, 5.3, 9.3, 7.4, 6.6, 6.3, 7, 5.7, 6.7, 6.9, 6.9, 6.6, 5.3, 6.5, 5.7, 7.5, 6.3, 6.8, 7.3, 5.9, 7.1, 6.9, 7, 7.6, 7, 7.1, 6.5, 5.2, 5.8, 6.2, 6.4, 6.7, 5.3, 7.3, 7, 7.3, 8.6, 6.2, 5.8, 5.8, 6.6, 7.1, 6, 9.5, 7.3, 8, 7.3, 6.5, 9, 8.2, 7.3, 6.5, 7.8, 7.4, 6.9, 7.3, 6.2, 7.5, 7.6, 7.1, 6.3, 6.9, 7.5, 7.7, 8.3, 7.4, 5.2, 7, 6.6, 6.5, 7.5, 6.3, 8.1, 6.9, 6.8, 8.1, 7.4, 7.2, 9.2, 7.8, 6.6, 6.1, 8.3, 6.2, 9.2, 7.4, 9, 8.6, 7.1, 5.8, 6.5, 6.4, 5.7, 7.1, 7.5, 8.4, 5.9, 7.2, 8.8, 8.2, 7.6, 8.8, 8.9, 5.7, 7.1, 6, 7.7, 6.3, 5.6, 7.5),
`GRAAF-PRI Grafentheorie opdracht` = c(8.4, 7.5, 8.7, 9.3, 7.5, 8.8, 7.8, 6.8, 6.3, 7.2, 7.2, 7.6, 7.1, 7.1, 8.5, 9.1, 1.4, 8.6, 6.8, 9, 7.6, 8.5, 6.2, 8.7, 7.6, 6.4, 6.7, 7.3, 8.2, 7.6, 7.6, 7.5, 6.7, 8.6, 6.5, 8.2, 7.4, 8.9, 9.2, 9, 7.4, 8.1, 6.9, 7.2, 5.5, 6, 6.3, 5.9, 8.3, 8.8, 8.7, 8.3, 7.8, 6.3, 7.6, 8.2, 8.2, 7.5, 8.8, 7.5, 7.7, 7.7, 7.8, 7.2, 8.9, 6.9, 8, 9.7, 7.4, 7.9, 9.8, 7.9, 8.9, 5.9, 7.8, 7.8, 7.4, 7.8, 8.1, 8.6, 8.7, 8.4, 8.8, 8.4, 8.5, 6.3, 6.9, 8.6, 8.4, 7.5, 1, 8.4, 7.6, 6.9, 6.8, 6.4, 6.1, 8.9, 8.2, 7.9, 9.4, 9, 7.5, 6.4, 8.8, 6.8, 9.7, 9.7, 9.7, 6.3, 7.9, 7.2, 6.4, 7.6, 8.9, 7.4, 8.8, 5.9, 7.2, 8.6, 7.5, 6.4, 8.5, 5.3, 7.5, 6.3, 6.4, 7.9, 6.8, 7.8, 8.6, 9.2),
`GRAAF-THI Grafentheorie theorie` = c(6.6, 7, 7.3, 8.3, 6.3, 9.7, 5.9, 5.2, 4.5, 7.7, 5.9, 7.2, 6.7, 6.4, 10, 6.5, 7.3, 8.7, 7.4, 5.8, 9.3, 7, 9.4, 7.4, 8.2, 9.4, 7.4, 5.6, 7.1, 6.1, 5.5, 8.4, 10, 6.9, 6.3, 5.5, 5.3, 6.8, 6.2, 6.7, 8, 8.8, 7.4, 6.5, 7.4, 4.3, 6.1, 9.4, 5.7, 7.5, 6.5, 6.3, 9.3, 8.9, 6, 9.5, 5.6, 7, 10, 9.1, 7.4, 7.5, 6.1, 7.4, 3.5, 8.3, 9.7, 7.2, 7.9, 5.7, 7.8, 8, 6.5, 5.5, 7.2, 8.4, 6.5, 7, 6.6, 6.4, 8.6, 5.8, 3.2, 9.6, 6.5, 9.8, 7.2, 6.7, 6.7, 6.4, 6.1, 5.4, 8.1, 6.6, 7, 5.7, 6.7, 7.9, 5.3, 7.7, 7.7, 7.3, 7.8, 9.3, 9.8, 7.7, 8.2, 7.4, 7.6, 4.2, 5.5, 9, 7.1, 6, 6.1, 6.3, 6.7, 4.9, 5.4, 8.9, 9.8, 4.3, 8.4, 6, 8.6, 8.4, 7.3, 7.1, 7.5, 9, 7.1, 8.6),
`BWISK-TH|Basiswiskunde` = c(8.5, 9.3, 6.7, 5.5, 8.7, 8.6, 6.8, 6.1, 7.7, 5.2, 5.4, 8.9, 6.3, 6.1, 7.2, 6.3, 5.8, 9.4, 5.5, 3.8, 9.3, 9.4, 6, 7.3, 5.4, 6.3, 5.3, 5.7, 8.7, 6.9, 4.7, 6.6, 6.2, 6.9, 5.8, 4.8, 5.8, 9, 6.3, 6, 6.1, 8.1, 7.1, 6.2, 6.3, 8, 6.1, 6.3, 4.7, 7.7, 5.9, 6.2, 4.9, 6.6, 6.5, 8.4, 3.4, 7, 7.4, 8, 9.8, 8.5, 5.5, 7.1, 6.1, 5.3, 8.2, 4.2, 7.6, 5.3, 5.2, 9.5, 6, 5.9, 8.5, 5.9, 5.4, 6.2, 6.2, 9.2, 5.7, 3.3, 6.2, 8.3, 9.4, 6.5, 8.3, 9.4, 5.3, 6.3, 7.6, 6.2, 6.5, 6.6, 8.3, 6.1, 5.8, 7.6, 4, 8.5, 5.2, 8.5, 7.4, 8.5, 8.6, 6.4, 5.8, 3.8, 5.1, 7.7, 5.8, 7.8, 5.5, 7.1, 6, 6.1, 9.4, 4.2, 5.5, 5.4, 8.9, 7.7, 9, 4.3, 5.4, 4.7, 6.4, 8.5, 7.1, 8.2, 6.5, 7.2),
`CALEID-TH|Caleidoscoop theorie` = c("7.4000000000000004", "6.2999999999999998", "5.7000000000000002", "7.0999999999999996", "6.0999999999999996", "7.5", "5.5", "6", "5.0999999999999996", "6.5999999999999996", "6.2999999999999998", "6.5", "4.9000000000000004", "NA", "8.5", "6.9000000000000004", "3.2000000000000002", "7.2999999999999998", "4.2999999999999998", "4.7000000000000002", "7.9000000000000004", "8.6999999999999993", "5.2999999999999998", "6", "6.4000000000000004", "5.7999999999999998", "3.8999999999999999", "5.7999999999999998", "7.7000000000000002", "4.7999999999999998", "5.7000000000000002", "7.2000000000000002", "5.2999999999999998", "5.7999999999999998", "5.7999999999999998", "5.5", "5.7000000000000002", "8.9000000000000004", "6.4000000000000004", "5.7999999999999998", "4.7000000000000002", "5", "5.7000000000000002", "4.9000000000000004", "5.0999999999999996", "6", "5.7999999999999998", "5.5999999999999996", "6", "6.2999999999999998", "6.9000000000000004", "6.2000000000000002", "5", "5.5999999999999996", "NA", "8.5999999999999996", "4.2999999999999998", "7", "8.9000000000000004", "5.2000000000000002", "5.2000000000000002", "6", "5.5", "6.7999999999999998", "3.6000000000000001", "5.9000000000000004", "8.9000000000000004", "4.4000000000000004", "6.2000000000000002", "6.2000000000000002", "6.2000000000000002", "5.2999999999999998", "5.5999999999999996", "6", "7.5999999999999996", "6.5", "7.5", "4.2999999999999998", "6.2000000000000002", "8.5999999999999996", "6", "4.7000000000000002", "3.6000000000000001", "8.4000000000000004", "8.9000000000000004", "6.2999999999999998", "8.1999999999999993", "8.8000000000000007", "6.5999999999999996", "4.4000000000000004", "8", "6.5999999999999996", "6.0999999999999996", "6.0999999999999996", "8", "6.2000000000000002", "5.2999999999999998", "6.2000000000000002", "5.7999999999999998", "7.4000000000000004", "6.5", "8", "6.9000000000000004", "4.5", "7.5999999999999996", "6.0999999999999996", "6.0999999999999996", "4.7999999999999998", "6", "5.5999999999999996", "5", "5.4000000000000004", "4.4000000000000004", "5.4000000000000004", "6.2999999999999998", "7.4000000000000004", "9", "6.2000000000000002", "5.5", "6.2000000000000002", "7.7999999999999998", "6", "7", "5.9000000000000004", "6.2000000000000002", "4.2999999999999998", "7.0999999999999996", "5.4000000000000004", "7.5999999999999996", "5", "5.7999999999999998", "6.9000000000000004"),
`COVA1-PRI Communicatieve vaardigheden 1` = c("7", "6", "6", "7.5", "5.5", "7.5", "6", "8", "7.5", "7.5", "6", "6", "7", "6.5", "8", "6.5", "NA", "6.5", "6", "7.5", "7", "7.5", "5.5", "6.5", "6.5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "6", "7.5", "6", "5", "7.5", "6.5", "7.5", "NA", "7.5", "7", "8.5", "8", "6", "7", "8", "6.5", "7.5", "7", "5", "7.5", "6.5", "7.5", "8", "7.7000000000000002", "5.5", "6", "7.5", "7.5", "6.5", "7.5", "6.5", "6", "5.5", "6", "6", "5.5", "6", "8", "6.5", "7.5", "5.5", "6", "7", "8", "8.5", "7.5", "8", "7", "7.5", "8.5", "7.5", "8.5", "7.5", "5.5", "7.5", "7.5", "6", "6.5", "7", "7", "8", "6.5", "7", "8", "NA", "6", "8", "6.5", "8", "7.5", "6.5", "6", "7.5", "7.5", "6.5", "7.5", "6.5", "6.5", "6.5", "6", "8", "6.5", "6", "6", "6", "7", "6", "7.5", "6.5", "NA", "8", "6.5", "7.5", "7", "6", "6", "6.5", "6", "6", "6.5", "6.5", "6", "8"),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Could you add sample data to your question?

Comment: Could you explain to me how I can upload a sample data doc? It is a matrix with 5 columns and 132 grades (scaled 0.0 to 10.0).

Comment: Use ````dput````. On your console, execute ````dput(<your matrix name>)````. The output that you get, if re-run would generate the matrix again.

Comment: The output edited to the question... Is this ok?

Comment: Please update your R snippet by using code block rather than just doing a copy paste.

Comment: You should really consider the *minimal* advice on the [mcve] help page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fifth and sixth columns in the dataframe are of `character` class. For you to perform numeric operations like `length`, you would need to pass a `numeric` value. Also, some of the rows in fifth column have 'NA' values. We would also need to handle that.

Perform the following on your dataframe.

```
# Convert NA values to 0
data[data=="NA"] <- 0

# Convert columns from character to numeric
data[[5]] <- as.numeric(data[[5]])
data[[6]] <- as.numeric(data[[6]])
```

**EDIT:** Just found that you cannot save pie chart object to variables to use later. One possibility for you is to use the method provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286485/create-several-pie-charts-in-r-from-lists). Another option would be to use `plotly` instead.

```
# Updated function using plotly

library(plotly)

plotfunc <- function(data) {
    pie_charts <- list()
    for(i in 1:ncol(data)) {

        slices <- c(count_if(lt(5.5), data[,i]), count_if(gt(5.4),data[,i]))
        lbls <- c("Passed", "Failed")
        pct <- round(slices/sum(slices)*100)
        lbls <- paste(lbls, pct)
        lbls <- paste(lbls,"%",sep="")
        pie_charts[[i]] <- plot_ly(labels = lbls, values = slices, type = 'pie')
    }
    pie_charts
}

# Pass the dataframe to the function

plots <- plotfunc(data)

# The 'plots' array will have individual plots
# This will print the first plot
plots[[1]]

# The second...and so on
plots[[2]]
```

Hope this is clear!

Comment: I get the following error:
"Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, CALEID.TH.Caleidoscoop.theorie, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 132"

Comment: Try using ````data[[5]]```` instead of the actual column name.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, but the list pie_charts appears to be empty...?

Comment: @J.O.P.P. You have to return the list ````pie_charts```` inside your function. Else your function will not return any value. Edited my answer. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for updating the function! But can you tell me how to I check what's inside the list?

Comment: Updated the answer. Does this help you? If yes, please close this thread.